# awk to find match using unique id between two files and append data to second file

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to skip the `#` in `f1` and match `$4` in `f1` with `$6` of `f2` and if there is a match the contents in `$5` in `f1` are appended to `$8` in `f2`.
I added comments as well.

**f1**   `tab-delimited`

```
#
#
chr1    2019345 2030758 GABRD   {There is a lot of text here}
```

**f2**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    2028270 2028270 G   A   GABRD   This has text in it.
chr1    2028297 2028302 CAT C   GABRD   This has text in it.
chr1    2229406 2229406 A   G   SKI This has text in it.
chr1    2304553 2304553 G   A   SKI This has text in it.
chr1    2306636 2306636 C   T   SKI This has text in it.
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    2028270 2028270 G   A   GABRD   This has text in it.    {There is a lot of text here}
chr1    2028297 2028302 CAT C   GABRD   This has text in it.    {There is a lot of text here}
chr1    2229406 2229406 A   G   SKI This has text in it.    unknown
chr1    2304553 2304553 G   A   SKI This has text in it.    unknown
chr1    2306636 2306636 C   T   SKI This has text in it.    unknown
```

**awk**

```
awk '/^[^#]/                                 # skipping lines starting with # in f1
  FNR==NR{                                   # checking condition which will be TRUE when f2 is being read.
     a[$4]=$6                                # creating array a with index of $4 and value of $6 here.
     next                                    # next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
     print $0,($4 in a?a[$4]:"unknown")      # Printing current line and checking if 1st field is there in and print a[$4] else print unknown.
}' f1 f2                                     # close and inputs
```

Comment: The current text in `f2` `$8` is just a place holder that is empty.... I was just trying to indicate that the data goes her, sorry :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- skip all lines (all files) that start with a `#`
- `f1/$5` does not contain any embedded tabs
- if `f1/$4 == f2/$6` then replace `f2/$8 with f1/$5` else set `f2/$8 = "unknown"`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }
/^#/    { next }
FNR==NR { a[$4]=$5; next }
        { $8= ($6 in a) ? a[$6] : "unknown" }
1
' f1 f2
```

This generates:

```
chr1    2028270 2028270 G       A       GABRD   This has text in it.    {There is a lot of text here}
chr1    2028297 2028302 CAT     C       GABRD   This has text in it.    {There is a lot of text here}
chr1    2229406 2229406 A       G       SKI     This has text in it.    unknown
chr1    2304553 2304553 G       A       SKI     This has text in it.    unknown
chr1    2306636 2306636 C       T       SKI     This has text in it.    unknown
```